# I am a shape and yet I'm a letter

Tags: riddle

> I take direction and help find density.
>
> I am the graph of a function where none of it is negative.
>
> But I am not used to make equations
>
> Nor am I one to raise to power.

What am I?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You are

> V

I am a shape and yet I'm a letter

> V is a letter, and it can describe a shape, e.g. migrating birds fly in a V-shape.

I take direction and help find density.

> V points downwards. It's in the denominator of the formula for density, $\rho=\frac mV$.

I am the graph of a function where none of it is negative.

> The graph of the absolute-value function is shaped like a V.

But I am not used to make equations
Nor am I one to raise to power.

> It's not `<`,`>` or `^`.

Comment: I interpreted "I take direction" as v being the mathematical symbol for velocity, which is a vector (i.e. velocity having both speed and direction)

Comment: I don't quite understand why V can't be part of an equation. In fact, it is in the formula for density.

Comment: @KevinOrr "<>" is used to write equations. Its a latex syntax.

Comment: For `I take direction`, could it be because of V sounds like "way"? And I am not very much to the explanation "...fly V-shape", what about "W-shape" and "X-shape", every letter can be a shape this way.

Comment: *inequation*, an equation is just the opposite. I was confused by this, too. Many languages (LaTeX, SQL, Pascal, ...) use `<>` as *not equal*.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck what exactly does `<>` do in latex? I'm having a hard time finding it in the documentation.

Comment: @KevinOrr < and > are used for the _in_equalities "less than" and "greater than".

Comment: @ClickRick no its literally used as <equation>. It is a font setting.

Comment: Sorry I havent been on in forever! But there's your accept.

Answer (score 9):

Are you

> Mass, $m$

I am a shape and yet I'm a letter

> Every mass has a shape and is represented by $m$.

I take direction and help find density.

> Mass can be given a direction by a velocity vector, etc. $Density$ $= \frac{mass}{volume}$.

I am the graph of a function where none of it is negative.

> All values of a probability mass function must be positive.

But I am not used to make equations

> $m$ is generally not the variable in an equation. For instance, in graphing kinetic energy the velocity is the variable of concern.

Nor am I one to raise to power.

> I can't think of where mass is squared or cubed...but I'm really tired right now.

Comment: Good, but doubt it's right as m is definitely used in the equation e=mc2

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> Volume

I am a shape and yet I'm a letter

> Volume is a shape, and a volume (drive) on a computer is usually designated by a letter

I take direction and help find density.

> Volume (of a radio for example) can go up and down, and density is found by dividing mass by volume

I am the graph of a function where none of it is negative.

> I'm thinking this could be related to integrals (in 2D space this would be Area, but this must be 3D space?

But I am not used to make equations

> Rules out any operators, volume itself isn't used to make equations

Nor am I one to raise to power.

> Rules out ^ as the answer

I don't like my chances here, the explanations aren't really that solid.

Answer (score 1):

Long shot the letter I (capital i)

I take direction and help find density.

> > The I is basicly a line, the equation

```
   m
p=---
   v
```

> has a line in the center (it's a I rotated 90 degrees), it takes direction by the order of m/v if you change m/v from position the direction of the formula changes.

I know it does not answer multiple questions (yet) but the reason I belive it's the I:

**I** take direction and help find density.

**I** am the graph of a function where none of it is negative.

But **I** am not used to make equations

Nor am **I** one to raise to power.
What am **I**?